# How to retrieve the employeeid attribute

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

How to retrieve the `employeeid` attribute? I do not get any output when I execute:

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "Andre@contoso.com" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ExtensionProperty

Key                         Value
---                         -----
odata.metadata              https://graph.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/$metadata#directoryObjects/Mic...
odata.type                  Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
employeeId                  118880
onPremisesDistinguishedName
userIdentities              []
```

I do not know how to retrieve it with AzureAD PowerShell.

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "Andre@contoso.com" | Select-Object employeeId

employeeId
----------
```

Last update:

```
$_default_log = $env:userprofile + '\Documents\azuread_enabled_accounts.csv'
Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter 'accountEnabled eq true' |
    select DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, Mail, Department, UserType,
        CreationType, RefreshTokensValidFromDateTime, AccountEnabled,
        @{name='Licensed';expression={if($_.AssignedLicenses){$TRUE}else{$False}}},
        @{name='Plan';expression={if($_.AssignedPlans){$TRUE}else{$False}}},ObjectId |
    Export-Csv $_default_log -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Dictionary/HashTable which is a Key/Value pairs object, so Try:

```
(Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "Andre@contoso.com").ExtensionProperty["employeeId"]
```

Using your Example, added as last property:

```
$_default_log = $env:userprofile + '\Documents\azuread_enabled_accounts.csv'
get-azureaduser -all $true -filter 'accountEnabled eq true' | select DisplayName,`
UserPrincipalName,Mail,Department,UserType,CreationType,RefreshTokensValidFromDateTime,AccountEnabled,`
@{name='Licensed';expression={if($_.AssignedLicenses){$TRUE}else{$False}}},`
@{name='Plan';expression={if($_.AssignedPlans){$TRUE}else{$False}}},ObjectId, `
@{N="EmployeeId";E={$_.ExtensionProperty["employeeId"]} } | export-csv $_default_log -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: thanks I have edited my question. How can I add this hashtable within last update script?

Comment: Lastly can you see my other question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035299/azure-active-directory-v2-powershell-finding-all-licenced-office-365-users  thanks again