# Azure Active Directory V2 PowerShell - Finding all licenced Office 365 users

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, export-to-csv

I am trying to find all users of which have been assigned a specific license type.
I am basically trying to convert my Azure module v1 commands to Azure module v2 commands. how to get the same result as Azure module v1 commands ?

Azure V1:

```
$OutputFile = "C:\Export\O365LicensedADEnabledUsers.csv"
$T1 = @()
$O365Users = Get-MsolUser -All
ForEach ($O365User in $O365Users)
{
    $ADuser = Get-ADUser -Filter { UserPrincipalName -eq $O365User.UserPrincipalName } -Properties whenCreated, Department, Company, Enabled
    If (($ADUser.Enabled -eq $true) -and ($O365User.isLicensed -eq $true))
    {
        $T1 += New-Object psobject -Property @{
            CollectDate = $(Get-Date);
            ADUserUPN = $($ADUser.UserPrincipalName);
            O365UserUPN = $($O365User.UserPrincipalName);
            ADUserCreated = $($ADUser.whenCreated);
            ADUserDepartment = $($ADUser.Department);
            ADUserCompany = $($ADUser.Company);
            ADUserEnabled = $($ADUser.Enabled);
            O365Licensed = $($O365User.isLicensed)
        }
    }
}
$T1 = $T1 | Sort-Object -Property ADUserCreated
$T1 | Format-Table
$T1 | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
Write-Host "Output to $OutputFile"
```

Azure V2 :

AFAIK , there is no isLicensed property in Azure AD V2 powershell. I find AssignedLicenses property instead of this. but I am not sure.

```
    $OutputFile = "C:\Export\O365LicensedADEnabledUsers.csv"
    $T1 = @()
    $O365Users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true
    ForEach ($O365User in $O365Users)
    {
        $ADuser = Get-ADUser -Filter { UserPrincipalName -eq $O365User.UserPrincipalName } -Properties whenCreated, Department, Company, Enabled
        If (($ADUser.Enabled -eq $true) -and ($O365User.AssignedLicenses -ne $null))
        {
            $T1 += New-Object psobject -Property @{
                CollectDate = $(Get-Date);
                ADUserUPN = $($ADUser.UserPrincipalName);
                O365UserUPN = $($O365User.UserPrincipalName);
                ADUserCreated = $($ADUser.whenCreated);
                ADUserDepartment = $($ADUser.Department);
                ADUserCompany = $($ADUser.Company);
                ADUserEnabled = $($ADUser.Enabled);
                O365Licensed = $($O365User.AssignedLicenses)
            }
        }
    }
    $T1 = $T1 | Sort-Object -Property ADUserCreated
    $T1 | Format-Table
    $T1 | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
    Write-Host "Output to $OutputFile"
```

Comment: You probably meant to use `Get-AzureAdUser` in the second one instead of `Get-ADUser`. It seems like the AssignedLicenses property will never be null, so your check won't work. I'm guessing you have to check if it contains a SKU that you think is valid. [User entity documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity), [AssignedLicense documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#assignedlicense-type)

Comment: You can get the subscribed SKU's of a tenant with `Get-AzureAdSubscribedSku`. Then somehow figure out which ones among them are valid for your use case, and then check the user has one of those.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can you give me sample script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another easy way to check the whether user is licences via Azure AD V2 PowerShell is check the count of `AssignedLicenses` instead of check whether it is null.

This property is a array and as juunas mentioned, this property is not null-able. You can refer the code below to modify the piece of code:

```
 If (($ADUser.Enabled -eq $true) -and ($O365User.AssignedLicenses.Count -ne 0))
```

Comment: I assuming I will use ` If (($ADUser.Enabled -eq $true) -and ($O365User.AssignedLicenses.Count -eq 0))`for non-licenced users as well. Am I correct?